# Вставить в input значение введенное ранее

Tags: jquery

Есть поля

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
```

Также есть три radio кнопки

```
<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="sdek" class="shippingMethod">
<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="rupost" class="shippingMethod">
<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="pickup" class="shippingMethod">
```

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы если выбран **pickup**, то в поля *name* и *surname* вставить текст "самовывоз" и, при этом, сохранить введенные данные до выбора **pickup** чтобы если дальше будет выбран не **pickup**, то вставить в *name* и *surname* ранее введенные данные.

```
$(document).on('change', '.shippingMethod', function(){

if($(this).val() == 'pickup'){

var name = $(document).find('#name').val(), //переменная со значением до того как установить значение "самовывоз"
surname = $(document).find('#surname').val(), //переменная со значением до того как установить значение "самовывоз"

$(document).find('#name, #surname').val('Самовывоз');
}

else{

$(document).find('#name').val(name);
$(document).find('#surname').val(surname);


}

)};
```

Проблема - не вставляются ранее введенные значения (*var name, surname*) если после клика на **pickup** кликаю на кнопку .*shippingMethod* с другим значением (*sdek/rupost*). Поля тупо очищаются (или вставляются пустые значения).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сохранять введенные значения. Проще всего, наверное, при их  непосредственном изменении.
Когда меняете галку, вытаскивайте эти сохраненные.

```js
$(".fio").keyup(function(){
  $(this).data('value', $(this).val() );
});

$(".shippingMethod").change(function(){
  let v = $(this).val();
  console.log(v);
  
  if(v == 'pickup'){
    $(".fio").val("самовывоз")
  }
  else {
    $(".fio").each(function(){
       $(this).val( $(this).data('value') );
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="fio">
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="fio">

<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="sdek" class="shippingMethod">
<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="rupost" class="shippingMethod">
<input type="radio" name="shippingMethod" value="pickup" class="shippingMethod">
```